# Visual Studio Error - "The operation cannot be completed"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Recently Visual Studio has been giving me a pop-up error randomly (in that it doens't happen all time, but about 80% of the time) when I try and debug my program.  There are no build errors or warnings etc and I was running this fine before, but now it seems to be getting worse (and I haven't changed anything).  Further, the program only boots a console application, with the rest of the business logic (which is spread accross a number of projects) only being run when the user enters particular commands.

A couple of times Visual Studio has also frozen up.  I am running Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

The exact error is: "The operation could not be completed", and it comes up in a popup only giving me the option to click "Ok".   It seems to happen after I save changes (like changing a string...again no build errors though.

Cheers, any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Time to run the Visual Studio debugger to debug Visual Studio...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a VS 2008 specific fix to that error, not sure about 2010

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/40d2d241-a0c0-4137-9da9-e40611972c0e/