# Is this message an error?: "The Operation Can Not Be Completed"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've got a very simple Solution with a single Project in it. 
The project is just a simple WinForms, a config file to connect to sql-server, and 2 class files.

I've published the WinForms into production and it is working ok.

If I now open the Solution in VS and select the WinForms and press F5 I get an message "The Operation Can Not Be Completed" and the Winforms does not appear.

If, instead of F5 I use "Start Without Debugging" then it appears ok.

Should I be concerned about this message? If I should then how do I track down the reason behind it?

**EDIT**
Here are the debug options I have available:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Start Without Debugging" is simply starting last created exe file.

Comment: ok +1 - that option is not a great help then.

Comment: I see this post on [stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629994/visual-studio-error-the-operation-cannot-be-completed) but I'm using the latest version of VS and can't find the option mentioned

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal ... you deleted your answer: I only ever deleted one of my atempted answers! In 5 yrs time one atempted answer that is not correct isn't really a big deal!

Comment: Any chance your debug verison is currently running? so it cant be written over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES! That is an Error Message!

In the Debug tab of YourProject there is a debugger option for "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".

for more info check 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/40d2d241-a0c0-4137-9da9-e40611972c0e/

[image: Debug Tab]

Comment: I'm on a recent version of VS - I will add screenshots to the OP and maybe you can identify this option?

Comment: hey - JB it seemed to work; it has now given me a big warning about switch this off but the winForms now appears. Do you know what this "VS Hosting Process" actually does ? Have I turned off something important ?

Comment: The Visual Studio hosting process improves debugger performance and enables new debugger features, such as partial-trust debugging and design-time expression evaluation.

Comment: If it really helped you then you may flag it also as an answer, thnx

Comment: ok - so nothing vital is lost by disabling this feature - strange how this feature creates a bug by being turned on!

Comment: Yeah i know, i had it some time ago to ; )

Comment: (apologies JB - just attempting to extract as much info before marking it as the answer - thanks for the help)

Comment: Cools man, see more info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15331/discussion-between-whytheq-and-johnnblade)